# Searching date MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a row in my MySql table `'a'` with values `'date'='2015-06-01'` and `'hour' = 17:00:00`

My problem is that i can select this row by

```
hour BETWEEN "16:30:00" AND "17:30:00"
```

but i cant by `date = 2015-06-01`.

I need my full statement like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `a` 
WHERE (date = 2015-06-01)
AND (hour BETWEEN "16:30:00" AND "17:30:00")
```

Comment: Not a MySql expert, but have you tried writing `WHERE (date = '2015-06-01')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need quotes around the date too

```
SELECT * FROM `a` 
WHERE `date` = '2015-06-01'
AND `hour` BETWEEN '16:30:00' AND '17:30:00'
```

Comment: I'm sure i was trying with this, maybe something else was wrong, still thank you!